# Künneth theorem in a simple context

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

**Definition.** I say a topological space $Y$ has finite-type if $Y$ is a finite union of open sets $Y=U_1\cup \dotsb \cup U_N$ such that each possible intersection of the $U_i$ is either empty or is contractible to a point.

If $Y$ is finite-type, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to prove the Künneth decomposition formula for $X\times Y$ (where $X$ is an arbitrary topological space) using induction on $N$ above and Mayer–Vietoris.

To do so, the natural path is to consider the MV long-exact sequence of $Y=(U_1\cup \dotsb \cup U_{N-1})\cup U_N$, tensor it with the cohomology of $X$, and then use the Five-Lemma.

The issue is that tensoring with $H^i(X)$ could destroy the exactness.
(That's, of course, not an issue if we work over a field.)
Is there any way to fix this argument and make the desired conclusion?

Comment: In general you won't get an isomorphism (for the reason you mentioned) but just a spectral sequence.

Comment: Is this spectral sequence discussed somewhere? Is it possible to prove Kunneth theorem using that?

Comment: Presumably you can find reference somewhere, but I don't know where.  Yes, the Kunneth theorem is just the case when the spectral sequence degenerates.  Just consider spectral sequences as a generalizaion of long exact sequences, and see what you can do with an appropriate long exact sequence when $N=2$ (and what gets messed up by torsion).